# I can't create a new item to sell on Amazon.co.uk

Tags: amazon

I've just subscribed to Amazon.co.uk and I would like to sell an item. I noticed that if the item already exists in the lists and someone is selling it, I can easily click on "Sell yours here".

However if I need to post a new item, I can't find out how. Is because I need to buy an account first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information is a little buried on the Amazon website, but does come up on the [Pricing tab](http://services.amazon.co.uk/services/sell-on-amazon/pricing/) on the Sell on Amazon page. Near the end of the checklists you'll find the following:

[image: Amazon checklist showing listing is only available to pro accounts]

So with the free account you can only sell products already listed on Amazon, to list something new you'll need a £25 a month Pro account.